# Controlling internet speed Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to make an app which can slow down a user's internet speed. Is there any ways? It's for a gym sports events where whenever the runner is running on the threadmill and with their speed on the threadmill,the download speed of a file is changed. For example if the running speed is faster,download speed is faster. Is there any codes that are able to control the internet speed? I looked up on stacksoverflow but all is on simulator.

Answer (score 2):

There are no public APIs for doing this.  I would suggest that you instead fake the reporting of progress.

Comment: Ok got it. No wonder I couldn't find sources to control the internet speed unless by router,which would not be the objectives as that will slow the internet of the whole gym instead of one particular user

Answer (score 1):

If it is your app which is doing the downloading then if you implement the HTTP/FTP/whatever communication yourself over TCP/UDP your app can insert delays; or it can just download at network speed to a temporary location and transfer it from there to the correct destination at whatever speed it chooses.

If you are trying to slow down standard apps like Safari you could add a HTTP/FTP proxy to your system, which rather than simply proxying slowed down transfers. If you don't want to write a proxy from scratch take a look at Squid or GlimmerBlocker (I think its source is available, its in Java, this proxy is a Mac ad blocker demonstrating a proxy can be used for more than just proxying).

HTH, Have fun!